# Notification API - Ask permission after denied

Tags: javascript, html, push-notification, notifications

Is it possible to request permission to send push notifications again after user has clicked "Block" instead of "Allow" or closing the popup?

Simply running `Notification.requestPermission();` doesnt't trigger the permission request popup anymore.

`Notification.permission` returns `"denied"`

Comment: It is a normal behavious. You should not to disturb user if he chose 'denied'.

Comment: Ok, makes sense...

Comment: yes , but as a dev, if I blocked the permission by mistake on my own site, how can I reset the rights so I m asked again?

Comment: Chrome: chrome://settings/content/notifications
FF: Options > Privacy & security > Scroll to permissions > Notification --> Settings button
IE Edge: Settings > Advanced > Manage Permissions button

OR in some browsers you can right click on the lock button in the address bar and manage the settings of that site.

Comment: I know this is an old question and the answer is probably still no - but I'd like to revisit it and ask if anyone has a solution? My use-case is an internal web-app used on an internal company LAN only (never over the internet) - it absolutely needs popup notifications and will not function if they're disabled.... and users are not necessarily literate enough to know how to re-enable them if they accidentally hit deny.. I would instead want to pop up a message informing them that the app will not work unless they allow and then re-request. Otherwise it's a support desk nightmare...